# setting operating environment for multiple deployments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Goal: have an entity have its own database but with the same underlying application on a single VPS.

•  the VPS would have users created by an `identifier` value.
•  deployment would have each entity have its `deploy/identifier.rb`file;
•  that file (rather than deploy.rb) would define `set :deploy_to, '/home/identifier/application_name'`
•  postgresql users need creation and role attribution
•  finally `database.yml` gets configured as such:

```
identifier:
    <<: *default
    database: identifier_development
    username: identifier_username
    password: identifier_password
```

This will effectively deploy but in production mode by default, which is sensible.  But what if one wanted to deploy in develpoment mode?

The deployment process does complain at the assets compilation and db:migrate actions that

```
01 config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:
01
01   * development - set it to false
01   * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
01   * production - set it to true
```

However, the [documentation's configuration page](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/) does not reference how to state this (`eager_load`is not referenced on the page)

How can the rails environment be set via the `deploy/identifier.eb` file?

Comment: If you want to have per machine database settings you can just set the `DATABASE_URL` environmental variable which a lot simpler and more robust then generating the `database.yml` file at deploy time. That's how Heroku for example does it. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: Since the ENV var takes preceedence you can just configure the bare basics in `database.yml` - the adapter, charset etc. Having a rails app running in development on a publicly available host is a very bad idea due to the security concerns - it's not intended to be used like that and Rails and your gems may either leak sensitive data or leave plenty of venues for attackers to exploit.

Comment: You can set the Rails environment through the RAILS_ENV env var or by passing the -e option when running Rails (such as through the procfile). Note that you're not actually limited to the three environments that Rails ships with - you can create any number of environments like staging, ci etc. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#creating-rails-environments

Comment: You should not expect Capistrano to have any documentation about `config.eager_load` as that's a Rails specific setting which disables code reloading (the default for production and test).  Capistrano is just a tool for automating the deployment process of any kind of application. Not rails specifically. Sorry for the many comments but you really need to re-evaluate your idea here and see if you're just wildly overengineering a simple problem.